# The role of "at" in "They felt uncomfortable at the thought of being ridiculed in this manner."

Tags: prepositions

Which one of these definitions:

> - Expressing the time when an event takes place.
> - Expressing a particular state or condition.
> - Expressing the object of a look, thought, action, or plan.

of the preposition *at* does apply in this context:

> They felt uncomfortable **at** the thought of being ridiculed in this manner.

?

P.S. The definitions were quoted from the [ODE](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/at).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Cambridge Dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/at)

One of the definitions of the preposition **at** is listed by the dictionary as

> used to show the cause of something, esp. a feeling.

Similar sentences are

*I was so excited at the news.*

*I was nervous at being left alone.*